Can I skip 'email verified' page with a custom policy for Azure-AD-B2C?
On this signup flow with Email Verificaiton:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup/media/flow.png
Is it possible to ignore/skip the 3rd image, the one with "E-mail address verified. You can now continue"?

In your picture images 1, 2 and 3 are one step. We resolved this issue with custom Javascript that detects successful email verification and clicks the Continue button instead of the user... ;) unfortunately I can't share that code as it's a customer project

At a high level, we opted to inspect the HTTP requests made by B2C with jQuery's ajaxSend, and if we detect a successful verification, it automatically clicks the button.

@juunas hi, thx a lot for sharing this. I give it a try.

Or... you can just emit a click event on 3rd step with a MutationObserver.. it's just idea :D

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

As others have suggested you have a few options:

Look at the ajax response of the verification and click the button in JavaScript

Add a MutationObserver and look for the aria-disabled attribute mutating on the continue button (example below of such function)

Get rid of the separate verification screen in favour of Display Controls


    function handleContinueButtonMutation(mutationList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutationList.length; i++) {
            if (mutationList[i].type === 'attributes'
                && mutationList[i].attributeName === "aria-disabled"
                && mutationList[i].target.attributes["aria-disabled"].value === "false") {

                $("#continue").click();
            }
        }
    }

 var observerConfig = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false, subtree: false};
 var observer = new MutationObserver(handleContinueButtonMutation);

 observer.observe($("#continue"), observerConfig);
 

